# Adicionar UITabbarController sem storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

Como faço para adicionar uma **UITabbarcontroller** com **UINavigationController**, mas eu gostaria de adicionar em uma segunda view, porque tenho a tela de login de inicio e não gostaria de exibir a tabbar nessa primeira view, achei alguns exemplos mas todos adicionavam esses controles na AppDelegate alguém saberia como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

```
    UITabBar *suaTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    suaTabBar.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:suaTabBar];
```

Comment: Valeu amigo obrigado, essa é a forma correta de adicionar sem usar storyboard?

Comment: Sim! Com esse trecho de código, você criará manualmente uma TabBar, sem precisar de um StoryBoard.

Comment: Eu posso adicionar um **UINavigationController** normalmente neste caso?

Comment: Sim, sem problemas, nesse caso você terá que colocar esse trecho também na sua NavigationController.

Comment: Errado Leonardo, você não inicializa a Navigation e depois a Tabbar... O correto é fazer a inicialização da TabBar e para cada viewcontroller que ela conter, você alloca uma NavigationController ou uma View normal (no exemplo eu dou um set no conjunto de viewcontrollers) 

Exemplo: 
    UINavigationController *navSearch =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[BCCSearchViewController alloc] init]];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navSearch]];
    [navSearch.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-pesquisa"]];
    [navAnuncie setTitle:@"Anuncie"];

Comment: Você teria algum exemplo de como de como posso implementar isso?